# How to put assembly markers to C++ code (x64)

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, visual-studio-2005, 64-bit, marker

I need to put markers to C++ code that should be visible in assembly or binary. It seems it’s straight forward to do it for 32 using inline assembly:

```
__asm {
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
}
```

or using DB assembly statement:

```
__asm {
     DB  0x00, 0xFF, 0x10
}
```

But VisualStudio 2005 and better does not support inline assembly for x64. Is there any way to do it? Probably I can make a function in separate assembly module but how I can be sure that linker will put an actual assembly there instead of CALL?

Comment: The linker doesn't put in `CALL` instructions, it just puts in the actual address. The compiler will have put in the `CALL` to your assembly. But why do you need this? Isn't a `CALL well-known-address` usable as a marker?

Comment: Yeah, it might be the way: find the marker and it's address and then find CALLs of this address.

Comment: Actually, its good solution. There is some related article http://www.codereversing.com/blog/?p=69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a global volatile variable somewhere, say `volatile __int64 blah = 0;`. Then wherever you want some marker, use `_InterlockedCompareExchange64(&blah, SOME_UNIQUE_CONSTANT1, SOME_UNIQUE_CONSTANT2);`. You'll be guaranteed to find instructions loading `ECX:EBX` with `SOME_UNIQUE_CONSTANT1` and `EDX:EAX` with `SOME_UNIQUE_CONSTANT2` followed by `LOCK CMPXCHG8B` (0xF0, 0x0F, 0xC7, etc -- see instruction encoding details).

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk4z78b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says you can use intrinsic functions.

Comment: might be more helpful to point to the `__nop` intrinsic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983381(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/26td21ds.aspx says "Also, the optimizer can expand the intrinsic differently". I wonder can optimizer remove NOPs at all.

Comment: @Activation - The optimizer can expand the intrinsic differently for different parameters. Like doing `memcpy` better for fixed size blocks than for variable lengths. If you add `__nop` you obviously want it there, so the compiler wouldn't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MyAsmCode.asm
.code
  MyFunction proc
  ...
  MyFunction endp
end
```

compile it (ml64.exe).

You get object file (MS COFF 64): MyAsmCode.obj

In VS add MyAsmCode.obj to linker additional dep.

Now you can call this function. ;)

Comment: how you can be sure that linker will inline MyFunction instead of performing CALL?

Comment: Describe the details for what you need it, I think I can help you